# Two dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays:

```
$name = Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 )

$id = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )
```

And I would like to sort by `$name` value, but I don't need, where is 0
But when I do this:

```
foreach ($name as $key => $n) {
if ($n ==0 ){} else{
    echo "valami[" . $key . "] = " . $n . "//" .$id[$key]."";
}}
```

I lost the correct $id[$key]

Please help me!

The `$_POST`:

```
<?php echo "<form name='pdf_form2' action='pdf.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    $berelhetok = getreclist("SELECT *, count(*) as count FROM rent GROUP BY rent_id ORDER BY rent_id");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, count(*) as count FROM rent GROUP BY rent_id ORDER BY rent_id");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    foreach($berelhetok as $berel){
    echo "<tr>
    <td><select name='name[]'>
    <option  value='0'></option>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo "<option  value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>
    <td align='center'>".$berel[rent_id]."</td>
    <INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id[]' VALUE='".$berel[rent_id]."'>
    <td align='center'>".$berel[rent_megnevezes]."</td>
    <td align='center'><img src='".$berel[rent_kezdokep]."' width='100px' /></td>";
    } ?><INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="menu_id" VALUE="<?=$menu_id;?>">

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Mentés" class="button"> 
</td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: what language is this? looks like it could be PHP, but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter) to filter those element having value 0

e.g

```
$name = array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 1, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0 );

$id = array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 5, 5 => 6, 6 => 7, 7 => 8, 8 => 9, 9 => 10);

$name = array_filter($name);
foreach ($name as $key => $n) {

    echo "valami[" . $key . "] = " . $n . "//" .$id[$key]."";
}
```

Output:-

```
valami[0] = 2//1
valami[1] = 1//2
```

Comment: But I need to get the $id value, so I want this:
sort $name value and write the $id value

Comment: Can you please write your expected output:-

Comment: It's good, and I need to sort $name like:

valami[0] = 1//2
valami[1] = 2//1

Comment: So I think, I need to merege this two arrays, but I don't know how. IT's a sample, but I have bigger arrays.

Comment: yes, so I need to merege the values I think.
for example: valami[4] = 2//5 valami[5] = 1//6 to valami[0] = 1//6 valami[1] = 2//5

Comment: So my problem is, this is a multiple  $_POST,  $_POST['name'] and $POST['id']  And I don't know how can I merge the $name to $id, because I have to know which $name value has $id value. And when I sort this the  Array[] number is change and I lost the $id.  Do you understan me? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I would like to sort the $_POST by the $name (the $namefield not include name, it is the counter field, what the author could set up) field.